# Is there a way to replicate keyword LIKE from SQL in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote the following function for String and Dictionaries Exercise #2 of Python Course from Kaggle at [kaggle.com/learn/python](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/python) :

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    ind = []
    for i, j in enumerate(doc_list):
        for k in j.split():
            if (len(k.strip().split(',')) > 1) or (len(k.strip().split('.')) > 1):
                if keyword in k.lower():
                    ind.append(i)
            elif (keyword == k.lower()) and (i not in ind):
                    ind.append(i)
    return ind
```

The main problem I had was at the moment of splitting the strings if an item contained a character like ',' or '.'  as the following list:

```
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car, and a horse", "Casinoville"]
```

I wasn't able to come up with a short logic to do the comparison, unless I did further splitting or at least two loops.

By the way, the solution that Kaggle provides is the following:

```
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    # list to hold the indices of matching documents
    indices = [] 
    # Iterate through the indices (i) and elements (doc) of documents
    for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
        # Split the string doc into a list of words (according to whitespace)
        tokens = doc.split()
        # Make a transformed list where we 'normalize' each word to facilitate matching.
        # Periods and commas are removed from the end of each word, and it's set to all lowercase.
        normalized = [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in tokens]
        # Is there a match? If so, update the list of matching indices.
        if keyword.lower() in normalized:
            indices.append(i)
    return indices
```

I was wondering if there is an easier implementation using regex as in SQL when querying with LIKE(%string%)?

I thought about using something like fuzzywuzzy, but that would defeat the purpouse of the practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for regex you can use Python `re` library which in particular provides tools for splitting a string on a regex pattern. For example, to split a string `my_string` on all occurrences of either `.` and `,` you can use:

```
import re
re.split(r"[,.]", my_string)
```

Second, your code does not really use split strings, you are just checking if a string contains either `.` or `,`. This can be done with regex too, but it can also be done without it, e.g. as follows:

```
any(c in my_string for c in ",.")
```

This expression will return `True` if the string `my_string` contains either `.` or `,` and `False` otherwise.

Finally, your solution to the exercise is not quite correct. The string `"I live in Casinoville."` (with a period at the end) will be recognized as containing the keyword "casino", but according to the description of the exercise, it should not be.

Comment: I tried out both using any() instead of OR when checking 'k' and it works even with "I live in Casinoville." I hadn't thought about the re library, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use pandasql to query pandas using sql.